# Axiom dependency version required by spring web service 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws, axiom

What is the version of Apache Axiom to be used with 2.0. I'm trying to use Axiom 1.2.8 and it is throwing some method not found error.

I've a annotated end point as given below.

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "employeeUpdateRequest", namespace = "http://www.example.org/goservices-ws")
@ResponsePayload
public EmployeeUpdateResponse update(
        @RequestPayload EmployeeUpdateRequest request,
        MessageContext messageContext) throws EncryptionException {
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info("Inside UpdateEnabledStatusEndpoint");
    }

    EmployeeUpdateResponse response = new EmployeeUpdateResponse();

    return response;
}
```

The request is successfully reaching my endpoint but when I returns the response it is throwing a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory.createOMElement(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMDataSource;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMSourcedElement;
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapBody.setStreamingPayload(AxiomSoapBody.java:71)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessage.setStreamingPayload(AxiomSoapMessage.java:175)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.marshalToResponsePayload(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.handleMethodReturnValue(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:284)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:237)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:230)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:172)
```

What is the reason for it? How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search through the svn source, I found that the version needed is Axiom 1.2.9.